# Would installing RPM cause any problems?

Tags: java, linux, putty

Would installing rpm with a server running on putty effect it?I need it so I can start updating java while the server is set up would affect it.

Thanks

```
    CentOS release 6.6 (Final)
    x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Here is the operating info that it shows when you log in to putty.

Comment: Installing rpm with a virus in it will definitely cause some problems.

Comment: Maybe ask this on Arquade? To be honest I'm not sure it belongs here, even though it contains a query about programming tools, it's primarily about Minecraft

Comment: I suggest to give a try to http://unix.stackexchange.com , or to http://superuser.com .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install multiple versions of java and switch it using the alternatives utility. After installing java (using yum or rpm) you can use alternatives to set de default vesion of java that the OS will use.

Example:

```
alternatives --config java
```

Output:

```
*  1           /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.91-1.b14.el7_2.x86_64/jre/bin/java
 + 2           /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.101-2.6.6.1.el7_2.x86_64/jre/bin/java
```

The + indicates the current version of java that the OS is using.

If you execute `java -version` you'll see this output:

```
java version "1.7.0_101"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.6.6.1.el7_2-x86_64 u101-b00)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.95-b01, mixed mode)
```